# Use DFS with Mac OSX

Tags: mac-osx, dfs

Windows Server DFS (Distributed File System) isn't supported on Mac OSX.
E.g. the user can't connect to DFS root and browse the file structure but has to connect to each server separately.

What is the best (and inexpensive) way to get it to work please?

Thanks a lot,
Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [ADmitMac](http://www.thursby.com/products/admitmac.html) before to enable various AD functionality on Macs, including DFS support.

There's no native DFS support in the SMB/CIFS client in 10.6.

Comment: This is absolutely correct.

Comment: The [pricing](http://www.thursby.com/pricing/admitmac-standard-pricing.html) on that seriously looks ugly $120-179 per-machine depending on volume seems like it would be very painful.

Comment: I can only imagine how painful it was to develop software to add all these capabilities to OS X.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need DFS, pricing with DAVE (www.thursby.com) starts at $119 and quickly drops from there in larger quantities.  ADmitMac is probably an overkill that includes DAVE technology as well as commercial grade active directory support with both WGM and GPO management support.